# PHP - Check if a value is in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi guys is there any way to check with PHP if a value already is in an Array and if so to get new value (No duplicates)?

I tried to store the **unique** **ids** in a Session and then to look in the Session if there was same id found to get new result else to store the id in the Session

```php
$sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM fragen ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$record = $this->db->query($sqlStatement);
if(!$record){
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Data could not be loaded from Database. Error: ".$this->db->error);
}
$result = $record->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['ids'] = $result["id"];

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['ids']); $i++){
    if($_SESSION['ids'][$i] == $result["id"]){
        $sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM fragen ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $record = $this->db->query($sqlStatement);
        if(!$record){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Data could not be loaded from Database. Error: ".$this->db->error);
        }
        $result = $record->fetch_assoc();
        break;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['ids'][] = $result["id"];
    }
}
var_dump($_SESSION['ids']);
$record->free();
return $result;
```

This solution may be very bad so please tell me a better way to solve this if you are able to.
It's just an exercise since I'm a beginner in PHP and MySQL

Comment: Did you type "php check if value is in array" in your favourite search engine yet??? This is not a new problem and is unlikely to need a new question or answer.

Comment: If you just want to make sure that each id only appears once, why don't you just use `$result['id']` as the second-level index rather than appending a blank one?

Comment: @ADyson if i found something usefull for me i would not ask a new question...

Comment: @droopsnoot what is a second-level index?

Comment: There are so many wrong things in your code. `$_SESSION['ids']` used as array and normal value. `break;` after you found something. Increasing size of $_SESSION with previous found id, but also use `sizeof()` in your `for`. First time `sizeof($_SESSION['ids'])` return the size of a value not size of an array.

Comment: @Foobar so i need count?

Comment: Dont get my wrong, but you need any kind of basic logic here. And no you dont need count, this change would help `$_SESSION['ids'] = $result["id"];` to `$_SESSION['ids'][] = $result["id"];`. But that makes the code not really better. Also it seems just an example code, with the `random()   LIMIT 1` stuff. Dont know what you want to do.  If you just want to know if an value is in an array do `in_array('foobar',array('foobar'))`

Comment: i want if i found same id in array to get new result in array

Comment: so that only the array is returned which was had not the same values as the values of the arrays before

Comment: Maybe this helps you to structure your code? https://3v4l.org/bILiF. It will keep generating a random number if until it finds one which doesn't exist in the target Session array, and add it if it doesn't. It's unclear why you weren't using in_array in your version (which is why I thought maybe you hadn't googled it)

Comment: Ok thanks @ADyson this looks helpfull i will try it out

Comment: Thank you all for the help

Comment: If you solved it, please add an Answer below. The solution is not part of your question! Until then, your question will appear to be unanswered and will be less prominent in searches etc. Also, people can't vote on your solution if you hide it in the question area. Take the [tour] if you're unsure how Stackoverflow's Question and Answer format works. I rolled back your inappropriate edit, but if you want to retrieve what you wrote in order to add it to the answer you can get it from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74825099/revisions) of your question. Thanks.

Comment: [You don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`. It is just noise here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541). Please also see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to the helpful comments i now managed to solve this excercise like i wanted. Here is the code which works so far.

```
$sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM fragen ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$record = $this->db->query($sqlStatement);
if(!$record){
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Data could not be loaded from Database. Error: ".$this->db->error);
}
$result = $record->fetch_assoc();

while (true){
    if(isset($_SESSION['ids']) && count($_SESSION['ids']) == 3){
        $result = [];
        break;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['ids']) && in_array($result["id"], $_SESSION['ids'])){
        $sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM fragen ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $record = $this->db->query($sqlStatement);
        if(!$record){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Data could not be loaded from Database. Error: ".$this->db->error);
        }
        $result = $record->fetch_assoc();
        }
    else {
        $_SESSION['ids'][] = $result["id"];
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($_SESSION['ids']);
$record->free();
return $result;
```

The number 3 is the number of the entries in the table